# Understanding Rails Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to understand the way how active record associations work. So far, I thought I figured it out, but not sure anymore.

Anyway, I'm building my very own CMS and apart from all, I'll focus on my main problem. I'm having a table *pages* and *pictures*:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :headline_image_id
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string   :name
      t.string   :description
      t.string   :image
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

With this I have my models:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :headline_image_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :headline_image, class_name: Picture, foreign_key: :headline_image_id
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And that's it. Now after I create a picture and a page which has the id of a picture in the headline_image_id attribute, I can fetch that headline_image with *@target_page.headline_image*. Perfect, but the thing that is bothering me is the readability of the code. Wouldn't it make much more sense if I associated the two models in the Page model like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :headline_image_id, presence: true

  has_one :headline_image, class_name: Picture, foreign_key: :headline_image_id
end
```

If I do it like this and run *@target_page.headline_image* I get a SQL Constraint exception that tells me there is no headline_image_id in the pictures table.

I read all the Active Record Association tutorial on Ruby on Rails Guides and watched all the codeschool Rails courses, and I was pretty sure that everything was going to work with a has_one association...but it didn't.

Can someone please explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) provides an explanation as to why you're experiencing the problem. Essentially, when you declare a `belongs_to` relationship, the foreign key appears on the table for the class declaring it. When you declare a `has_one` relationship, the foreign key is on the table for the class in the declaration.

#### Example

In this scenario, the `pictures` table would require a `page_id` foreign key.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page 
end
```

In this scenario, the `pages` table would require a `picture_id` foreign key.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page
end
```

If you wanted to use a `has_one` association, just remove the `headline_image_id` column from your `pages` table and add a `page_id` column to your `pictures` table. You can do this in one migration. After you run the migration, change your model definitions as per my above example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bart! It works this way :)
Can you explain just one more thing. What if I'm having on a page a headline_image and a thumbnail_image (which can be a different picture all together...not only different size). What would be a good approach then? I would have a page_id in the pictures table for headline_image, but what with the thumbnail_image? Just put another column in the pictures table and name it differently?

Comment: If you're interested in setting up something like that, I would highly recommend you setup _Single Table Inheritance_ for your `Image` model. I've provided more information in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/bjedrocha/df6d6f71a6ff2678c3d3). I hope this helps. Please accept my answer if you found it helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome and detailed answer! Thank you for your time and help :)